# conda and flask not logging anything

Tags: python, flask

I just started with python and am confused that my code does not behave the way the examples show.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'Server Works!'
  
@app.route('/greet')
def say_hello():
  return 'Hello from Server'
```

`conda run -n myenv flask run`

after this command, nothing appears, yet the app works.

Using VSCODE and Windows 10 Terminal

Comment: Where do you run that command and what do you expect to appear after it's executed?

Comment: @wombatonfire inside the PS terminal in vscode. `PS R:\projects\alpha\.py> conda run -n myenv flask run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see anything in the console is because `conda run` capture your output.

If you want to run the above command with `conda run`, you need to use the folowing command

```
conda run --no-capture-output  flask run
```

But I think you shouldn't run command like that. Activate the environment first and do anything in activated shell.

```
conda activate -n myenv
flask run
```